# forEach does not the expected filtering

Tags: dart

So i've tried to filter an ordinary List with some objects in it. In these Objects is an ID which should be just shown only once. My problem is that this does not work.
When I try to just output the single ID, it  works:

```dart
List container = [];

haltepunkte.forEach((element) {
  if (!container.contains(element["LineID"])) {
    print(element['LineID']);
    container.add(element);
  }
});
```

This outputs my whole List just again when I call print on container.

```
[{StopID: 130, StopText: Seegasse, LineID: 101}, {StopID: 130, StopText: Seegasse, LineID: 101}, {StopID: 130, StopText: Seegasse, LineID: 101}, {StopID: 130, StopText: Seegasse, LineID: 101}, {StopID: 130, StopText: Seegasse, LineID: 101}, {StopID: 130, StopText: Seegasse, LineID: 101}, {StopID: 130, StopText: Seegasse, LineID: 101}, {StopID: 130, StopText: Seegasse, LineID: 101}, {StopID: 130, StopText: Seegasse, LineID: 101}, {StopID: 130, StopText: Seegasse, LineID: 101}, {StopID: 130, StopText: Seegasse, LineID: 101}, {StopID: 130, StopText: Seegasse, LineID: 101}, {StopID: 130, StopText: Seegasse, LineID: 101}, {StopID: 130, StopText: Seegasse, LineID: 101}, {StopID: 130, StopText: Seegasse, LineID: 101}, {StopID: 130, StopText: Seegasse, LineID: 101}, {StopID: 130, StopText: Seegasse, LineID: 101}, {StopID: 130, StopText: Seegasse, LineID: 101}, {StopID: 130, StopText: Seegasse, LineID: 136}, {StopID: 130, StopText: Seegasse, LineID: 136}, {StopID: 130, StopText: Seegasse, LineID: 136}]
```

But now, I just add the "LineID" to the List and just return the IDs and now it works:

```dart
List container = [];

haltepunkte.forEach((element) {
  if (!container.contains(element["LineID"])) {
    print(element['LineID']);
    container.add(element['LineID']);
  }
});
```

```
[101, 136, 538, 611]
```

Has anyone an idea why this happneds? My goal is to get back a List where every LineID is just in there only once.

Answer (score 2):

The reason are your `if` statement:

```
if (!container.contains(element["LineID"])) {
```

You are checking if the list are already containing the same `LineID` value. But if you are putting the whole element into the list like `container.add(element);` the list does no longer contain the value of `element["LineID"]` but instead the whole `Map` element.

The `contains` method does not check if a value can be found inside a `Map` object inside your list. It only checks if it can find any object which are `==` to another object.

**Update**

A solution is to use a `Map` to save the relation between LineID and element and use this to check if you already have the element. Then you can extract all the elements by getting the values of the map:

```
void main() {
  final containerMap = <String, Map>{};

  final haltepunkte = [
    {'LineID': 5, 'txt': 'test'},
    {'LineID': 6, 'txt': 'more tests'}
  ];

  haltepunkte.forEach((element) {
    if (!containerMap.containsKey(element["LineID"])) {
      print(element['LineID']);
      containerMap[element["LineID"]] = element;
    }
  });
  
  final container = [...containerMap.values];
}
```

Comment: Ahh okay. So any suggestions how I can solve this? Im a little bit out of ideas. Besides I had in my mind that there is a function for this but I might be wrong or on a different language.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you do `container.add(element)` you are adding the entire item from `haltepunkte`, not just the `lineID`. So when the condition `(!container.contains(element["LineID"]))` is checked, it is always true because the container list never has `element["LineID"]` in it, instead it is having the entire element. So as a result, it adds all the items from `haltepunkte` to `container`.

One way to go about filtering the list is..

```
haltepunkte.forEach((element) {

    bool isDifferent = true;

    for(int i = 0; i < container.length; i++){
      if(element['LineID'] == container[i]['LineID']) {
        isDifferent = false;
        break;
      }
    }

    if(isDifferent){
      container.add(element);
    }

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from your actual problem, don't make it more complicated than it has to be.

If you want to get the unique list of ids, then just do so, don't try to reinvent the wheel by doing it yourself:

```
var distinctIds = haltepunkte.map((element) => element["LineID"]).toSet().toList();
```

Once you have unique ids, you can for example get the first item for each id from your list:

```
var filtered = distinctIds.map((id) => haltepunkte.firstWhere((haltepunkt) => haltepunkt["LineID"] == id));
```

Granted, you loop is more efficient especially for really large numbers of items, but this is easy to read and easy to get correct. Beats efficiently being wrong most of the time :)

Comment: Thanks but this is exact what I dont need. :-)

Comment: Well, it's literally what you *said* you needed. Maybe if you clarify what you *need*, you will get a better answer.

Comment: LOL @Chris Pi, sure, it's my arrogance... you solve your little problem without my help. Bye.

Comment: Well at your edit it looks like you understood what I tried to achieve, so I guess it was not so unclear? Also your edit was something I thought my self aswell but I think its not very efficient. I will see and keep it in mind, thx!

Comment: I don't know... it looks like you can get pretty solid answers to problems on SO, assuming you stop insulting people that try to help you.